# How can I manage Node.js async variable scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I have the following code for populating my test database. The goal is to save the parent document after each of the child documents to the parent can have a reference to them.

```
function saveRecipe(ingredients, directions, recipe, done) {
    var ingredientSaveTasks = createSaveTasks(ingredients)
    var directionSaveTasks = createSaveTasks(directions)

    async.parallel([
        (callback) => { async.series(ingredientSaveTasks, callback) },
        (callback) => { async.series(directionSaveTasks, callback) }
    ], (err, results) => {
        recipe.ingredients = results[0] // The returned ids for each ingredient
        recipe.directions = results[1] // The returned ids for each direction
        recipe.save(done)
    })
}

function createSaveTasks(objs) {
    var saveTasks = []
    for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
        var saveTask = function (callback) {
            var obj = Object.assign({}, objs[i])
            obj.save((err, result) => {
                callback(err, result._id)
            })
        }
        saveTasks.push(saveTask)
    }
    return saveTasks
}
```

I've tried a few variations on this and I think it has to do with variable scope. However, I thought by deep copying my obj with *var obj = Object.assign({}, objs[i])* would save a "real" copy of the object for later use inside the async function.

Depending on which of the many way I've tried to make this work I end up with one of the following errors:

> TypeError: obj.save is not a function
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined

I've seen some talk about using .bind() to control variable scope but I'm not sure how to use it in this case.

Comment: What are ingredients and directions variables passed to createSaveTasks?

Comment: Arrays of Mongoose model objects, which contain a save function. If I put ingredients[0].save() as the first function of saveRecipe(), this ingredient is saved in the database. (just tried it to verify it works)

Comment: Ok, so what happen if you log objs[i] in the loop of createSaveTask function?

Comment: I see the Mongoose model object, still with a working save function. The issue is that the function no longer has access to this object when it gets executed in the async function. If I try to deep copy the object with Object.assign(), I actually end up with an empty object.

Comment: Well, so as you said bind is the solution, bind return a new function where you can specify the context assigned to the function (the value that you obtain when call "this" keyword inside the function) and/or the arguments passed to the function. So in your case var saveTask = function(callback){this.save(...)}.bind(obj[i]) with this you specify the context, so in that function your object will be accesible as "this"

Comment: This worked perfectly! And now I understand what bind does, redefines the "this" keyword as you said. Thanks a lot, just copy/paste your answer and I'll accept. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bind` return a new function and you can specify the context assigned to the function (the value that you obtain when call "this" keyword inside the function) and/or the arguments passed to the function. `Bind(thisArg, ...arguments)`. So in your case:

`var saveTask = function(callback){this.save(...)}.bind(obj[i])`

With this you specify the context, so in that function your object will be accesible as `this`.
Some examples:

```js
(function a(){console.log(this)}).bind({key : 'value'})();

var a = function(){console.log(this)}.bind({key : 'value'});
a();
```